# Ruby On Rails IDE for development on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, ide

There are many IDE's available today for the Ruby on Rails application development. I am somewhat confused after reading that which IDE should I use for ubuntu at present. The articles are older then a year now which gives the IDE information to use for. At work I am using eclipse IDE which is working well for now. But at home, I am thinking if there is anything better to use which is more friendly and easy for development now.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say if you're not familiar with ancient editors like emac or vim. You can try Sublime Text 2

Answer (score 2):

I would vote for vim with plugins that work perfectly with rails:

1- vim-rails : Which is really great with rails projects. Allows you to navigate pretty quickly between views, controllers and models. Using rakes and rails generators within vim itself. https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails

2- NERDTree :  for folders and files. https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree

3- Fugitive if you are using git this is a really awesome plugin. https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive

The beautiful thing about vim is that you can customise it as you like. You could add ruby autocomplete and exuberant ctags (http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) to quickly navigate between functions.

Vim has a steep learning curve but once you get used to it, it will add up huge benefit. Vimcasts is a great source to learn it. http://vimcasts.org/